# Get Bearer Token - Oauth 2

Tags: .net, api, oauth-2.0

The goal is to receive Bearer Token from this API. I have attempted this via Postman and was able to successfully receive one, but looking to automate via my app.

I am connecting to a 3rd party application and the requirements for a call to there API is using Oauth 2 connection. The required fields are clientID, ClientSecret, grantType, authURL, UserName, Password, and the redirectURI. I have tried numerous options but the below scenario is the closest I have been. When using the below script I get a StatusCode: 400 Bad Request.

```
Private Shared Function GetToken(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As String
    Dim pairs = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) From {
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("client_id", "ID"),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("client_secret", "secret"),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("auth_url", "https://URL/authorization"),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("username", userName),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("password", password),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5000/auth/callback")
}
    Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs)

    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Dim response = client.PostAsync("https://URL/token", content).Result
        Return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: change `userName` to `username` may fix the problem

Comment: Still same error

Comment: do you get response from postman with this exact params?